# Radio button me deja seleccionar más de una opción Angular 10

Tags: angular, web, radiobutton

Estoy haciendo un formulario en Angular 10 y tengo una parte donde utilizo radio buttons junto a *ngFor. Se trata de un cuestionario que permite al usuario contestar a varias preguntas, pero el problema es que se supone que solamente se tendría que poder elegir una opción, pero me deja seleccionar más de una. Este es mi código

```
<h2 id="pregunta" *ngFor="let questions of question; let i=index"><div *ngIf="i<1">
          {{i}}
          {{questions.question}}
        
        <form [formGroup]="form" *ngFor="let answers1 of answer1; let j=index"  method="post"> 
          
          <input id="answers1{{j}}" type="radio" name="preg1" value={{answers1.id}}/><label
          for="answer2">{{answers1.answer}}</label>

</form>

<button id="boton" class="button" type="submit"(click)="onSubmit()">Siguiente</button>
```

Gracias de antemano por la respuesta

Comment: El `*ngFor` no  debe ir en el formulario sino en el *input*, o en todo caso un contenedor que tenga dentro tu *input* y tu *label*, algo mas o menos así: `<section *ngFor="let answers1 of answer1; let j=index"><input ... ... </label></section>`. ;)